# Formula in Excel with a particular increment value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have  a requirement with Excel Formulas. I am trying to create an excel sheet with few columns. One of the columns has "Number of VMs"
Another Column has "Avg. Monthly Backup Data (GB)"

I would like to get the below result.

If the number of VMs is 1, the Avg Monthly Backup Data (GB) will be 429 GB
If the number of VMs is incremented by 1, the Avg Monthly Backup Data (GB) will be incremented by 430 GB

So if number of VMs is 2, the Avg Monthly Backup Data (GB) will be 429+430 = 859 GB and so on and so forth

How do i create the formula here so that the Avg Monthly Backup Data gets incremented  by 430 GB based on the Number of VMs

Comment: `=429+((A2-1)*430)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you need

```
=429+430*(A1-1)
```

propagated through all B cells with the respective number after A?

If not, show the third line in your trend you want to get.